# Create circle shapefile vector in QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing, circle

Is it possible to create a circle shapefile feature in QGIS, like it is possible to do in ArcMap?

I am trying to digitise a map wich features roundabouts, which I'd like to be part of the same polyline as the rest of the road. I've done this quite easily in Arc, but cannot work out how to create nice, polyline spherical features in QGIS.

Can anyone advise me of an editing tool that I'm hopefully missing?

Comment: plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/rectovalDigit/

Comment: That's for polygons only - I'm looking for polyline circles.

Comment: you can convert the polygon circles to lines...

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the plugin 'Rectangles Ovals Digitizing' for creating rectangles, circles and ovals.

[image]

Side note: Just read that the new geometry engine of the coming QGIS 2.10 supports curved geometry types. I am not sure how this would apply for circles.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what version of QGIS you are using. I have 2.8.2-Wien. This has advanced digitising tools that allow creation of circles by selection of two points, selection of three points, selection of centre and input radius and selection of a centre and a point.

Just ensure that you have the CADDigitize and CadTools plugins loaded to access some good digitising tools.